# R apply function with 2 dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I would like to use the mmetric function from the rminer package
I have two dataset (observation and prediction) and I would like to apply the function by column, how do I do it?

Prediction:

```
     aa     oo    dcl     iy     sh
   2.255  0.648 -0.111  0.111 -0.049
   0.239  0.753 -0.972  1.907  0.000
   2.521  1.072 -0.107  0.100 -0.068
   0.415  1.072  0.735  0.789  0.885
   0.101  0.629  0.293  0.740  1.562
   0.496 -0.260 -0.133 -0.078  0.108
```

Observation:

```
    aa     oo    dcl     iy     sh
   2.255  0.648 -0.111  0.111 -0.049
   0.239  0.753 -0.972  1.907  0.000
   2.521  0.403 -0.107  0.100 -0.068
   0.415  2.713 -0.637  0.789  0.885
   0.101  0.629  0.293  0.740  1.562
   2.606 -0.260 -0.133 -0.078  0.108
```

for the single column I can use

```
mmetric(obs[,1], pred[,1], mmetric = "MAE")
```

how do automatically apply this to the whole dataset? I tried with the "apply" and I searched how to pass more arguments, or how to work with more datasets/lists, but I didn't find any solution!

Thank you!

Comment: You could `lapply` over your both data.frames names. What I mean is `lapply(names(obs), function(x){mmetric(obs[x] , pred[x], mmetric = "MAE")})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to apply the function `mmetric` on the corresponding columns

```
mapply(function(x,y) mmetric(x,y, metric='MAE'), obs, pred)
#     aa        oo       dcl        iy        sh 
#0.3516667 0.3850000 0.2286667 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Or we don't need the anonymous function

```
Map(mmetric, metric='MAE', obs, pred)
```

Comment: are you sure about that? I tried and it is applying the function cell by cell, I got back 20265 results on the original 2 datasets with dimensions 4053 * 5

Comment: @Sojers I updated with the result I got.  As per your post, you have two data.frames.  I am assuming that you have two matrices instead of 'data.frames'.  In that case, `mapply(function(x,y) mmetric(x, y, metric='MAE'), as.data.frame(obs), as.data.frame(pred))`

Comment: thank you! The second dataset wasn't casted to data.frame, can you explain to me why is it working by column the map function? Is it possible to use it by row? or by cell? Just to understand the code and apply it to other problems!

Comment: @Sojers A matrix is a vector with dim attributes.  The elements in a matrix are just like a single element in a vector.  So, if you have a 5x5 matrix, by using `Map/mapply`, it will give 25 comparisons.  The `data.frame` is a `list` with elements of equal length.  So, either `data.frame` columns or `list` element act the same way as we expect.